# delete lines with sed match a special regex

Tags: regex, sed, match

I try to delete all lines that begin with some optional special chars followed by `blubb`:

That's the lines I want to match:

> #blubb
> *blubb
> -blubb
> blubb

That should do it, but doesn't work :(

```
sed "/^.?blubb$/d" -i special.conf  
sed "/^[#*-]?blubb$/d" -i special.conf
```

Has somebody the **right solution**?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use this sed command:

```
sed -i.old '/^[#*-]\{0,1\}blubb/d' special.conf
```

OR

```
sed -i.old -E '/^[#*-]?blubb/d' special.conf
```

OR

```
sed -i.old -r '/^[#*-]?blubb/d' special.conf
```

Comment: Ah yes `\?` and `\+` are GNU extensions.

Comment: I don't see how they would work even with GNU sed.  Once they are escaped with back-slash, they lose their special meaning (and they have those special meanings only when `-r` is specified).

Comment: Hello, this works perfectly for me too. But I don't understand what the option -i.old  and -E or -r does. Thanks

Comment: -i is for inline editing and -r or -E is for extended regex in sed

Comment: can u please explain what is the '.old' suffix ?

Comment: @chenchuk: That is used as extension for creating backup copy for inline editing.