# Delete line from file if matches regular expression

Tags: sed, text-files

I am attempting to delete a line from a text file if it matches a regular expression.  To accomplish this I was using `sed` in an Ubuntu environment combined with regular expressions.  I have tried/referenced the following solutions: [Sol1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956/regex-does-not-contain-certain-characters), [Sol2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822809/delete-lines-with-sed-match-a-special-regex), [Sol3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed?rq=1).

My current command is: `sed '/[^"]+},/d' test.json` with this command I am attempting to match and remove lines like:

```
{"hello},
{"go penguins!},
{"someone help1),
```

I am NOT trying to match or remove lines like: `"should not match regex"},` Any line that ends with `"},` should not be deleted.

I am not tied to using `sed` so any acceptable answer would work so long as my text file would look something like:

```
...
{"omg this is amazing"},
{"thanks for your help"},
{"no problem"},
...
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to delete any line with unbalanced double-quotes?

Comment: Yes @Beta that should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `sed '/\"},/!d' test.json`?

Answer (score 0):

It should by `sed '/\"},/d' test.json` (without `!`)