# How to remove characters from a string in a file starting from a given substring until the next n number of characters in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, vi

I have a file that contains a single line with usernames followed by their other information.

**For instance the file contains:**

Clara01{25 characters of info}Betty29{25 characters of info}Edith34{25 characters of info}Raji11{25 characters of info}

All in a single very long line with many usernames followed by 25 characters of their information.

Now, I want to **search Betty29** and then **delete/remove** the substring Betty29{25 characters of info}.
That is, how should I delete Betty29 and then next 25 characters.
How should I do that in Linux shell scripting?

I have read about sed command but I still could not figure out. I am new to shell scripting so please be kind.

Comment: `sed 's/Betty29.\{25\}//' foo.txt`

Comment: Go online, read about regular expressions and sed. Also look within SO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [delete lines with sed match a special regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822809/delete-lines-with-sed-match-a-special-regex)

Comment: @Xavjer This question isn't about deleting lines so I'm going to guess that no it's not a good choice of a dupe

Comment: @Shawn it worked and gave the output I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @Shawn suggested

```
sed 's/Betty29.\{25\}//' foo.txt
```

is getting the job done.

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Have you read up enough on (POSIX Basic) regular expressions to see how it works?

Comment: @Shawn I did read about it. I have a basic idea...

Answer (score 0):

0. Use `readarray -d'}'` to access the file as an array.
1. Search for an element starting with `Betty29` and `unset` that element.
2. Then `printf '%s'` the whole `"${array[@]}"` as an output.

```bash
unset_element() {
  local -r prefix="$1"
  local -a array
  local -i idx
  readarray -d'}' array
  unset 'array[-1]'  # empty
  for idx in "${!array[@]}"; do
    [[ "${array[idx]}" = "${prefix}{"* ]] && unset 'array[idx]' || :
  done
  printf '%s' "${array[@]}"
}
```

Now let’s test it:

```bash
input='Clara01{25 characters of info}'
input+='Betty29{25 characters of info}'
input+='Edith34{25 characters of info}'
input+='Raji11{25 characters of info}'

unset_element 'Betty29' <<< "$input"
```

Output:

```
Clara01{25 characters of info}Edith34{25 characters of info}Raji11{25 characters of info}
```

Presumably, this removes **all** occurrences of `Betty29`. If you want to remove only the **first** one and make it “more efficient”, just add a `break` into the `for`-loop once the match is found.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create a child process (`sed` or whatever), if I can do it easily within bash as well.

Say we have

```
line=abcBetty29abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Then we can do

```
new_line=${line/Betty29?????????????????????????//}
```

Since counting the 25 question marks is error-prone, an alternative would be to use a regex:

```
if [[ $line =~ ^(.*)Betty29.{25}(.*) ]]
then
  new_line=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
else
  echo pattern not found 1>&2
fi
```